Android navigate to child fragment programmatically without instantiating root fragment - nav graphs
I am seeking help with android nav-graph and navigation component, I have HomeActivity with NavHostFragment, I am looking for a solution where, HomeActivity checks for certain condition and navigate user to the child fragment and back to the Root on back button or nav up (like noramal nav behaviour), here is my navigation graph.
Android Navigation Graph
I have 3 fragments [A], [B], [C], 'A' and 'B' are root level fragments where 'A' is 'root' of the graph and 'C' is child of 'A', now in activity HomeActivity if condition is met, I want to navigate to the child 'C' fragment, and on back button or on navigate up, 'C' returns to 'A' right now I am using following method to navigate.
if (shiftcardSelected){
 val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_container) as NavHostFragment

  val navController = navHostFragment.navController
  if (navController.currentDestination?.id != R.id.shiftcardSaleEntries){
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_home_nav_item_to_shiftcardSaleEntries)
  }
}

The problem is, above mehtod instantiate fragment 'A' and then navigates to 'C', So whatever n/w and db calls made from 'A' is also gets executed.
I am looking for a solution in which, fragmet 'A' will not instantiate when navigating from HomeActivity and when on back button or navigate up will pop current child 'C' to 'A'.
Thanks in advance.
Your help is much appriciated. :)
